# debug build variant failing

Tags: android

I just pulled my (currently working on the google play store) app from github, tried to run it and keep getting this error...only on this build variant (DevelopDebug).

Does anybody know what this error means? Or have any recommendations on what I could try to fix this?

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaFukushimaDevelopDebug'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio 2.3.3.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''

Things I tried

1. Different builds. (others work, just not this one, Even the release version of this one works...just not the debug)
2. Tried running it on the same environment/computer that it was developed on and the same issues came up.
3. Copied the directory and made a new build variant. (both develop and release on the new directory work...but not the orginal)

Comment: Clean Project and see its result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete the .gradle file
2. Clean Your project.
3. Try to rebuild it.

If you did it then enable mutidex in app based build.gradle file.

```
multiDexEnabled true
```